# Include duplicate rows in a many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I have an `Event` class and a `Question` class. These form a many-to-many relationship. The pivot table has an additional `asking` column.

My database:

```
events (id)
questions (id)
event_question (id, event_id, question_id, asking)
```

My Event class:

```php
class Event {
    public function questions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class)
            ->withPivot('asking');
    }
}
```

Now for example, I may have duplicate Event-Question pairs in the pivot table, but the `asking` pivot column will be different.

```
id   |  event_id  |  question_id  |  asking
-----+------------+---------------+--------------
1    |  5         | 10            | 'purchaser'
2    |  5         | 10            | 'attendee'
```

I want Eloquent to fetch both rows, but instead it is only returning one of them.

```php
dd($event->questions->toArray());

// Should be 2 rows but there is only 1
[
  [
    'id'          => 1,
    'event_id'    => 5,
    'question_id' => 10,
    'pivot'       => [
      'asking' => 'attendee', // asking 'buyer' is missing
    ],
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is pretty simple, I just need to specify which columns are distinct:

```php
class Event {
    public function questions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class)
            ->withPivot('asking')
            ->selectRaw('DISTINCT questions.id, event_question.asking, questions.*');
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you just   ->with([
        'questions' => function ($query) {
            $query->groupBy('question_id');
        }
    ]) ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud why would that help? Both rows have the same `question_id`. And I wouldn't want to have to alter the query every single time I load the relationship

Comment: but now you forced your self with no duplicates for ever if you already into that why not validate before adding to not let any duplicates be created in the first place